# Working principle of a farinograph

Tags: bread, dough

I am thinking of building a farinograph, not as accurate as the ones used in lab, for my friend's project. I know that a farinograph measures the torque at the blades and estimates the viscocity of the dough. I have the following questions on the working principle:

1. What is the relation between torque measured and Barbender units?
2. I am looking for a more detailed explanation of working of a farinograph, what I know is very crude and does not help me build one. Please can anyone provide me with any literature which explains the working (more on the technical side).
3. Is it really true that by just measuring the torque, one can understand the quality of the produced dough ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm not sure, but I'm guessing this is off-topic.

Comment: Whether or not the asker is strictly off-topic, s/he is unlikely to get a useful answer here.  Is there another SE site for gadget-builders?

Comment: Ther's a [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and an [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).  Perhaps one of them would be a better fit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because construction of a farinograph is not a cooking question.

Comment: If you focus instead on just the relationship between torque/Brabender units and gluten, this _might_ be on topic.

Comment: OK as Erica suggested I will edit the question or post a new question about relation between barbender and torque. As senschen suggested, i will probably post the question about Farinograph on engineering SE. Thank you all